# How might I cast/convert a Nancy Dynamic object to a List<BaseObject>?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nancy

In this scenario, **SomeObject** inherits from **BaseObject**.

Using the Nancy Framework, I'm popping a **List** into the **ViewBag** as follows:

```
ViewBag.MyList = await repository.MyTable.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Within the cshtml file, I want to convert or cast the Nancy dynamic object in the ViewBag to List so I can utilise some common code to parse the BaseObjects in the list.

I've tried doing things like:

```
List<BaseObject> tmp = ViewBag.MyList as List<BaseObject>;
List<BaseObject> tmp = (List<BaseObject>)ViewBag.MyList;
```

But have been unsuccessful.

Any ideas on how to cast/convert?

Comment: `But have been unsuccessful.` is extremely unhelpful. what does it mean?

Comment: it means I've been unable to work out how to cast/convert ViewBag.MyList (which ends up being a nancy dynamic type) to List<BaseObject>.